# Matching attributes list with or without quotes

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to match a list of attributes that may have quotes around their value, something like this:

```
aaa=bbb ccc="ddd" eee=fff
```

What I want to get is a list of key/value without the quotes.

```
'aaa' => 'bbb', 'ccc' => 'ddd', 'eee' => 'fff'
```

The code (ruby) looks like this now :

```rb
attrs = {}
str.scan(/(\w+)=(".*?"|\S+)/).each do |k,v|
  attrs[k] = v.sub(/^"(.*)"$/, '\1')
end
```

I don't know if I can get rid of the quotes by just using the regex.

Any idea ?
Thanks !

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but have you considered just using an XML/HTML parser, like Nokogiri?  Depends on the scope of what you're doing, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the pipe for the possible attribue patterns, which is either `EQUALS, QUOTE, NO-QUOTE, QUOTE`, or `EQUALS, NO-WHITESPACE`.

```
str.scan(/(\w+)=("[^"]+"|\S+)/).each do |k, v|
  puts "#{k}=#{v}"
end
```

Tested.

EDIT | Hmm, ok, I give up on a 'pure' regex solution (that will allow whitespace inside the quotes anyway).  But you can do this:

```
attrs = {}

str.scan(/(\w+)=(?:(\w+)|"([^"]+)")/).each do |key, v_word, v_quot|
  attrs[key] = v_word || v_quot
end
```

The key here is to capture the two alternatives and take advantage of the fact that whichever one wasn't matched will be nil.

If you want to allow whitespace around the `=` just add a `\s*` on either side of it.

Comment: Just tested it. There's no difference with my own regex, the quotes are still present in the value so I get this: ccc="\"ddd\""

Comment: Ah, oops, sorry, I simplified it just before posting and broke it.  Can't quite remember what the original was now. I'll post back :)

Comment: The problem with that it that you get two different match-group. So it doesn't work well since if there are no quotes it will be group-3 and if there are group-4. I tried a lot of things like this before asking the question. but thanks :)

Comment: 2 or 3 in this case due to the non-capturing group, but you're right.  That's why I assign to the hash using `a || b` and allow ruby to give me the one with a non-nil value.

Comment: You're right, sorry I didn't see the ||. Well that's also a workaround but at least less messy than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the quotes in the regex, but only if I matched the quotes as well.

```
s = "aaa=bbb ccc=\"ddd\" eee=fff"
s.scan(/([^=]*)=(["]*)([^" ]*)(["]*)[ ]*/).each {|k, _, v, _ | puts "key=#{k} value=#{v}" }
```

Output is:

```
key=aaa value=bbb
key=ccc value=ddd
key=eee value=fff
```

(Match not =)=(Match 0 or more ")(Match not " or space)(Match 0 or more ")zero or more spaces
Then just ignore the quote matches in the processing.

I tried a number of combinations with OR's but could not get the operator precedence and matching to work correctly.

Comment: What happens for attributes like `foo="one two three"` ?

Comment: It fails if there are spaces inside the quotes

Comment: Yes I tried some things like this but when quotes are present it's generally because of spaces in the value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ruby, but maybe something like `([^ =]*)="?((?<=")[^"]*|[^ ]*)"?` works?